# JQuery navigation menu

Tags: jquery, colors, navigation

```
var navObject = {
padLeft : '20px',
padLeftHover : '40px',
goRight : function(obj){
    if (!obj.parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
        obj.stop(true, true).animate({ 'padding-left' : this.padLeftHover }, 'fast');
    }
},
goLeft : function(obj){
    if (!obj.parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
            obj.stop(true, true).animate({ 'padding-left' : this.padLeft }, 'fast');
    }
},
makeActive : function(obj) {
    obj.siblings().each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            navObject.goLeft($(this).children('a'));
        }
    });
    if (!obj.hasClass('active')) { 
        obj.addClass('active');
    }
}

}$(function() {
$('#navigation li a').hover(function() {
    navObject.goRight($(this));
    $(this).css({
    "color": "red", 
    "position": "relative",
    "font-size": "20px"});
}, function() {
    navObject.goLeft($(this));
    $(this).css({
    "color": "yellow",
    "font-size": "14px"});
});

$('#navigation li a').click(function() {
    navObject.makeActive($(this).parent('li'));
    navObject.goRight($(this));
    return false;
});});
```

hi..  i have this jquery codes and what i'm doing here is a vertical navigation bar in a website

my prob is, when i hover my navigation menu it does all the CSS in my codes. but when i click the menu, i want the text to stay red. not go back to yellow..

thanks for the time for helping me out .. ^_^

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fH7pv/ => there.. the javascript does not work in fiddle, i dont know why..

Comment: jquery needed to be loaded using the first dropdown on the left, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/fH7pv/1/

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you click? (it stays red for me in the fiddle)

Comment: oh i see ok.. ^_^ thnx for that...

Comment: when you click, the text should stay red. not go back to yellow

Answer (score 0):

So, you click first, which sets red. *Then* you mouseout, which will set the text back to yellow. I would suggest you use classes. On click, add a class, on hover (mousein/mouseout), add and remove a different class. That way, when you click, you click color will "stick."